# Plot chart on x-axis using Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

[image]

How to create a chart horizontally using Highcharts

Answer (score 0):

You can easily present such a data set using Highcharts in various ways. Below is a demo of how to present this data set using a line chart in one of many ways.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2023, 9, 6, 6),
      pointInterval: 3600 * 1000,
      connectNulls: true
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [null, 5, 16, null, 8, 19, null, 13, 12]
  }, {
    data: [60, null, 3, null, 12, null, 5, null, 4]
  }]
});
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3wvxgyp0/